# Ошибка в выходе в главное меню

Tags: unity3d

Есть ошибка! Не знаю, как пофиксить. Есть кнопка паузы, нажимая на неё игра останавливается и повляются другие две кнопки. Кнопка выхода в главное меню и кнопка продолжить играть. Кнопка продолжить играть работает, а кнопка выйти в главное меню нет. Если кто знает, есть ли ошибка в коде?

```
public void Exit()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}

public void PauseOn()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    player.enabled = false;
    PauseScreen.SetActive(true);
    PauseButton.SetActive(false);
}

public void PauseOff()
{
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    player.enabled = true;
    PauseScreen.SetActive(false);
    PauseButton.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Дайте угадаю, данный скрипт висит на игроке?)

Comment: Не угадали) Он висит на камере.

Comment: Замени свой нолик в LoadScene() на имя сцены

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Заработало.